# Github Project is in subfolder instead of root

Tags: eclipse, git, github

A Project which i uploaded in eclipse to github is in
(For example my project is called SuperHero)

/SuperHero/SuperHero

but i want it in the root of the Project

/SuperHero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just seems you have an extra folder either created by Eclipse or you. The easiest way would be to do this on the command line. I'm going to assume you want to retain the first folder because that's the folder containing `.git` and the container of your git project. As such the steps below basically move all the contents from `SuperHero/SuperHero` to `SuperHero`. I'm not sure what Eclipse is doing here so I'm going to give you the instructions to remove the extra folder and update the changes in GitHub. At this point you might need to re-import the project in Eclipse.

On a `terminal` or `gitbash` navigate into the first `SuperHero`

`cd ~/whateverpaththisis/SuperHero`

Lets move all the files from the second `SuperHero` folder into the first:

```
mv /SuperHero/* .
```

Remove the empty `SuperHero` folder:

```
rm -R SuperHero
```

Check if all the changes make sense with:

```
git status
```

Commit the changes:

```
git commit -am "Removed extra folder created by eclipse"
```

Push the changes

```
git push origin <branchname>
```

If you now go to GitHub you should see the project laid out in the project's homepage without a containing `SuperHero` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Helped! Thank you!